# Time series prediction when data is not i.i.d

Tags: time-series, distributions, predictive-models, forecasting

I have time series data $y_t$ with covariates $x_{1,t}, x_{2,t}, ...$.  The covariates represent budgets for different programs.  I can create an ARIMAX model that fits the data very well so far.

In the future, the budget for $x_{1,t}$ is going to be cut.  Can I still make predictions based on my ARIMAX model?  For current data, $y_t$ is predicted well because it is greatly driven by $x_{1,t}$.  In the prediction set, my values for $x_{1,t}$ will be nothing like what they were in the training set where my model was created.  How can I resolve this problem of not i.i.d data?  Is there a different model or technique that will handle this better?

Answer (score 4):

Did x1 ever have a similary low volume in the history?  If yes, then you are ok.

If no, The covariates in the future are "outside the range of historical experimentation" and the model can't be used.

See more here

"It is inappropriate to predict new values when X is outside the range of X's used to build the regression equation. This is called extrapolation."

http://www.stat-help.com/linreg.pdf